# grep, else print message for no matches

Tags: bash, loops, grep

In a bash script, I have a list of lines in a file I wish to grep and then display on standard out, which is easiest done with a while read:

```
grep "regex" "filepath" | while read line; do
    printf "$line\n"
done
```

However, I would like to inform the user if no lines were matched by the grep. I know that one can do this by [updating a variable inside the loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) but it seems like a much more elegant approach (if possible) would be to try to read a line in an until loop, and if there were no output, an error message could be displayed.

This was my first attempt:

```
grep "regex" "filepath" | until [[ -z ${read line} ]]; do
    if [[ -z $input ]]; then
       printf "No matches found\n"
       break
    fi
    printf "$line\n"
done
```

But in this instance the read command is malformed, and I wasn't sure of another way the phrase the query. Is this approach possible, and if not, is there a more suitable solution to the problem?

Comment: In your first example, only the grep is needed and you get the same behavior. Is this just an for an example or is what you really want to do?

Comment: Does it? Could you demonstrate how? I'm still quite new to bash and don't understand how to use grep to get that behaviour. The code I wrote demonstrates the end result I'm trying to achieve, to answer your question.
Ah the cat is redundant. Removed, thank you.

Comment: grep prints the matching lines to its standard output by default, that's why the while/read loop works it is reading standard input. Just run `grep "regex" "filepath"` and you should see your matching lines.

Comment: `while read line; do` is the same as `until ! read line; do`. There's very little difference between the two; which one you use depends more on how you want to negate (or not negate) the condition than anything else.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all if you simply want to display a message when there's no match. Instead you can use grep's return code. A simple `if` statement will suffice:

```
if ! grep "regex" "filepath"; then
    echo "no match" >&2
fi
```

This will display the results of grep matches (since that's grep's default behavior), and will display the error message if it doesn't.

A popular alternative to `if !` is to use the `||` operator. `foo || bar` can be read as "do `foo` or else do `bar`", or "if not `foo` then `bar`".

```
grep "regex" "filepath" || echo "no match" >&2
```

Answer (score 3):

John Kugelman's answer is the correct and succinct one and you should accept it.  I am addressing your question about syntax here just for completeness.

You cannot use `${read line}` to execute `read` -- the brace syntax actually means (vaguely) that you want the value of a variable whose name contains a space.  Perhaps you were shooting for `$(read line)` but really, the proper way to write your `until` loop would be more along the lines of

```
grep "regex" "filepath" | until read line; [[ -z "$line" ]]; do
```

... but of course, when there is no output, the pipeline will receive no lines, so `while` and `until` are both wrong here.

It is worth emphasizing that the reason you need a separate `do` is that you can have multiple commands in there.  Even something like

```
while output=$(grep "regex filepath"); echo "grep done, please wait ...";
    count=$(echo "$output" | wc -l); [[ $count -gt 0 ]]
do ...
```

although again, that is much more arcane than you would ever really need.  (And in this particular case, you would want probably actually want `if`, not `while`.)

As others already noted, there is no reason to use a loop like that here, but I wanted to sort out the question about how to write a loop like this for whenever you actually do want one.

In fact, your code would read one line at a time, and terminate when it receives the first non-empty line of output from `grep`. A much better fix if that was what you actually wanted would be `grep -m 1 "regex" "filepath"` (presuming then that your regular expressions cannot match empty lines).

Also, your initial `while` loop is completely redundant. `grep` already prints its matches to standard output; you don't need to separately run `printf` on each (and if you really wanted to do that, you should use a format string; your code would do the wrong thing if any matching line contained a `%` character).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jordanm, there is no need for a loop in the use case you mentioned.

```
output=$(grep "regex" "file")
if [[ -n $output ]]; then
    echo "$output"
else
    echo "Sorry, no results..."
fi
```

If you need to iterate over the results for processing (rather than just displaying to stdout) then you can do something like this:

```
output=$(grep "regex" "file")
if [[ -n $output ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # do something with $line
    done <<< "$output"
else
    echo "Sorry, no results..."
fi
```

This method avoids using a pipeline or subshell so that any variable assignments made within the loop will be available to the rest of the script.

Also, i'm not sure if this relates to what you are trying to do at all, but grep does have the ability to load patterns from a file (one per line). It is invoked as follows:

```
grep search_target -f pattern_file.txt
```